# большой образ Docker

Tags: docker

При создании Docker образа приходится тянуть 8GB пакетов с хост системы.

Методом COPY, потом удалять. Но вывод `docker images` показывает размер контейнера с учетом скопированных в слое ранее пакетов. И при каждом следующем релизе образ растет все больше.

Какой механизм можно использовать для доставки пакетов на время генерации образа?

Comment: вы устанавливаете пакеты, **что-то** с помощью них делаете, а потом удаляете? это **что-то** можно сделать заранее, **вне** *docker-а*? если нет, то, насколько мне известно, выход только один — отказаться от использования *dockerfile-а*.

Comment: Мы пытаемся контейнеризировать ESB от IBM. Соответственно. Мы её устанавливаем, потом накатываем кучу .bar приложений гига на 3. И в итоге получаем образ 11GB, но дальше еще веселее, выходит релиз это +100-200MB. И образ растет и растет. Что с этим делать не понятно. Возникла идея делать VOLUME. Запускать контейнер. Накатывать "руками" новые апп, а после commit, но мне кажется, что это костыли.

Comment: либо попробовать монтировать  NAS-шару.

Comment: Каждая инструкция в докерфайле результирует в новом слое, и если инструкция добавляет 8 гигов, то они уже никуда не денутся и зависнут в соответствующем слое, даже если последующие слои их удалят. Вам не нужно делать руками commit, вам нужно просто пересобирать целиком все изображение при выходе нового релиза. Если вы завернете свою логику в баш-скрипт и будете выполнять внутри докерфайла, то вы сможете вовремя удалить лишние вещи, чтобы они не попали в конечную сборку,

Comment: Немного не так вы поняли меня. 
Если мы будем пересобирать весь образ при каждом релизе это займет часа 3, и никак не поможет избавится от установочных пакетов.

Comment: вместо директивы `copy`, вероятно, стоит воспользоваться директивой `volume`. судя по [приведённой информации](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume), смонтированный каталог будет доступен уже при обработке dockerfile-а.

Comment: эх если бы вы были правы, я бы не сидел второй день=)

Comment: VOLUME это как бы указание dokceru, что когда будет запуск контейнера, эта директория будет использована в качестве точки монтирования.

Comment: `Методом COPY, потом удалять` а вот это не о вашем случае? "Because image size matters, using ADD to fetch packages from remote URLs is strongly discouraged; you should use curl or wget instead. That way you can delete the files you no longer need after they’ve been extracted and you won’t have to add another layer in your image."

Comment: `and you won’t have to add another layer in your image.`

Comment: о моём, но требуется поднимать сервер раздачи пакетов.

Comment: слушайте, я так и сделаю! Об этом я думал, но второй идеей.
Спасибо - это и будет решение.

Comment: @ДмитрийСмирнов, вариант с отказом от *dockerfile-а* **вообще** (т.е., использование связки *run* + *commit*), мне кажется, вполне работоспособен, ведь при *run-е* можно монтировать *volume-ы* и сразу же использовать информацию с них. главное — в таком варианте вообще не будет никаких «промежуточных» образов — сразу конечный.

Comment: Да, я думал об этом, но прийдеться написать кучу кода для сборочного конвеера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый оптимальный вариант, использовать статик сервер. И Wgetom тянуть установочные пакеты.

Answer (score 2):

После создания окончательного образа вы можете сжать все слои в один. Это позволит сократить образ, так как из него будут удалены удаленные файлы. Сейчас эти файлы по прежнему хранятся в образе в других слоях.

Самый простой способ. Запустить ваш образ, что бы получить контейнер и потом выполнить вот такую команду

```
docker export <ID контейнера> | docker import - <новое имя образа>:<новая метка образа>
```

**Это приведет к потере всей истории образа**

Второй способ это использовать утилиту [docker-squash](https://github.com/jwilder/docker-squash)

```
docker save <id образа> > image.tar
sudo docker-squash -i image.tar -o squashed.tar
cat squashed.tar | docker load
```

Comment: Необязательно запускать образ: `docker container create <IMAGE>` создаст контейнер с каким-то именем (не <IMAGE>) и уже к нему можно применить [export](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_export/). Например, `docker export compassionate_bhabha > latest.tar`. Но файл стал не сильно меньше образа.

Answer (score 1):

Что бы уменьшить конечный размер имижда в конце каждой команде добавь "&& yum clean all" вот так:

```html
yun install httpd && yum clean all
```

это очистит загруженные файлы и уменьшит размер слоя в файловой системе и тем самым уменьшит размер итогового имиджа.
Для Ubuntu можно стирать /var/cache/apt/*

Answer (score 0):

Тут был кейс, что я юзал CentOS docker в CentOS по умолчанию поставлялся с aufs, с которым он некорректно работает. Требуется сменить на devicemapper и все будет ок.